# JavaScript code working with chrome but not working with Firefox

Tags: javascript

I have used below code to auto-update page tables in without reloading page. Its working fine with chrome but not working with Firefox. Any quick fix please.....

```
  var  nIntervId;
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                 nIntervId = setInterval(refresh, 2000);
            });

        function refresh(){
             var $table = $("table#mytable");
                 $.getJSON("http://www.scannerdemo.com/get_latest_verification/", function(obj){           
                    $.each(obj, function(key, value){
                    var rows = "";
                    var color_status="badge badge-inverse";
                    if (value.status=="Registered"){
                color_status="badge badge-info";
                }
                    else if((value.status=="Tampered") ||(value.status=="Tampered with line cut"))
                            {
                color_status="badge badge-important";
                }   
                    else if(value.status=="Verified"){
                color_status="badge badge-success";
                }           
                    rows=rows+"<tr>"+"<td><a href='/status/{{ record.asset_code }}'>"+value.asset_code+"</a></td>"
                        +"<td>" + value.scan_time + "</td>"
                        +"<td>" + value.credential + "</td>"
                        +"<td>"+"<span class='" + color_status + "'>" + value.status +"</span>" +"</td>"
                        +"<td>" + value.operator + "</td>"
                        +"<td>" + value.location + "</td>"
                        +"<td>" + value.auth_code + "</td>"
                        +"<td>" + value.emp_id + "</td>"
                        +"</tr>";
             $table.prepend(rows);

            });

        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: refresh method is not getting called

Comment: ctrl+f5 to refresh firefox cache?

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
                nIntervId = setInterval(function(){refresh();}, 2000);
```